# How to make a button move randomly when pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've searched everywhere to try and find an answer to this, but any answers that I've found don't work for me...
I want to make a button more randomly when pressed.
I know this is simple, and xcode doesn't pick up any problems.  When I run my code the simulater runs fine, apart from the fact that the button doesnt move.
Here is the code I used;

```
-(IBAction)Counter {
[self moveButton];
```

}

```
-(void)moveButton {
int xCo = arc4random() %200;
int yCo = arc4random() %200;
CGRect frame = Butoon2.frame;
frame.origin.x = xCo;
frame.origin.y = yCo;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.001];
Butoon2.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Thanks very much for your input!

Comment: First thing you need to learn is that `xcode` is an IDE and not a language, so that makes this question has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` so I have removed that tag and added the `objective-c` tag. Also please have a read of the Apple coding guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html) reading this you will learn that variables (`Butoon2`) should start with lowercase so should be `butoon2`, variables and methods start with lowercase and Classes start with uppercase.

Comment: @Popeye Thanks very much for the quick reply... I will have a read!  Is that the only thing that is wrong?  Can you suggest anything else?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)Counter:(id)sender {
   [self moveButton];
}

-(void)moveButton {
   int xCo = arc4random() %(int)(self.view.frame.size.width-Butoon2.frame.size.width);
   int yCo = arc4random() %(int)(self.view.frame.size.height-Butoon2.frame.size.height);
   CGRect frame = Butoon2.frame;
   frame.origin.x = xCo;
   frame.origin.y = yCo;

   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.001];
   self.Button2.frame = frame;
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Thanks - it doesn't like the 'demo' bit - it say's "property demo not found on object of type 'ViewController *'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)moveButton {
int xCo = arc4random() %200;
int yCo = arc4random() %200;
CGRect frame = Butoon2.frame;
frame.origin.x = xCo;
frame.origin.y = yCo;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.001
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^(void) {
                     Button2.frame = frame;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion... unfortunately it still doesn't work :'(

Comment: Check the value of `Button2`, maybe it is nil