# How can I create an event to move a button randomly?

Tags: ios, uibutton, xcode6

I have a button in a game and it is called redDot1. I have it located on my storyboard and it works great, but when the ScoreNumber is 10 or higher I want it to move around the screen to a random position and once it gets there it moves to another random position.. In Scratch, this was called glide if anybody is familiar with scratch. I uploaded a video of what I mean by showing the orange dot. [YouTube](http://youtu.be/i5Cy8ErqqE0)

Here is the code for my ScoreNumber where I would want to begin the movement.

```
-(void)Scoring{
ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
_score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", ScoreNumber];
if (ScoreNumber > 10) {

   //float circles;
}
}
```

I imagine inside that where it says float, I would call an event [self levelUp];

How do I create an event for redDot1 to begin moving?

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317108/how-to-make-a-button-move-randomly-when-pressed) to no success.

I tried creating this event.

```
-(void)levelUp{
UIButton *redDot1 = (UIButton *)redDot1;

int xmin = ([redDot2 frame].size.width)/2;
int ymin = ([redDot2 frame].size.height)/2;

int x = xmin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.width - redDot2.frame.size.width);
int y = ymin + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.height -   redDot2.frame.size.height);


[redDot2 setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];


}
```

EDIT: To answer comments, I am using auto-layout and constraints. and when I try this code...nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using auto layout? Also, is it moving to a new location and stopping or is it going to keep going, bounce around, interacting with other controls, etc. Or just a very simple animate moving it to a new location?

Comment: You need to describe what you mean by "float around the screen". You should also say why the method you tried didn't work. What did it do?

Comment: What is this line, UIButton *redDot1 = (UIButton *)redDot1; supposed to be doing? Do you have an IBOutlet called redDot1? When you use auto layout, you should not set any frames. You should move your view by modifying its constraints.